# How to add body class to front page & an internal page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, href

The jQuery function below works properly, and adds a `full` class to the `<body>` HTML element on the `/signin/` page based on the URL.

```
// add full class to sign in page body based on url

$(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
    if(/signin/.test(loc)) {
    $('body').addClass('full');
  }
});
```

I want to accomplish the exact same thing on the front/home page, or `/` URL within this same function. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide some further clarification - what element are you trying to attach the additional class too?

Comment: @aphextwix I want to add a `full` class to the `<body>` HTML element.

Comment: See my answer. I believe you are looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes are slow. A faster way:

```
function() {
    var loc = window.location.pathname; // returns the pathname
    if(loc == '' || loc == '/') {
        $('body').addClass('full');
    }
});
```

Comment: @LizBanach Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Using an appropriate regex. `/^\/$/`in your case.

```
/^\/$/.test('/') // true
/^\/$/.test('/asdf')  //false
```

Further adding to it in your case. I would, use `window.location.pathname`

```
$(function() {
    var loc = window.location.pathname; // returns the pathname
    if(/^\/$/.test(loc)) {
        $('body').addClass('full');
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. My final code is:

`// add full class to sign in page body for bg image

$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.pathname; // returns the pathname
  if(/signin/.test(loc)) {
    $('body').addClass('full');
  }
  if(/^\/$/.test(loc)) {
      $('body').addClass('full');
  }
});
`